# RabbitMQ Shovel config with Alternate-Exchange

Tags: configuration, rabbitmq

I'm trying to configure the Shovel plugin for RabbitMQ with a list of declarations. I have configured my remote exchange to have an alternate-exchange when I created it.

My problem is that I can't get the config file for shovel to include this argument so RabbitMQ crashes upon startup.

This is what my config looks like:

```
[
    {mnesia, [{dump_log_write_threshold, 100}]},
    {rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.4}]},
    {rabbitmq_shovel,
        [{shovels,
            [{call_stats_shovel,
                [{sources, [{broker, "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/test"},
                    {declarations,
                        [{'queue.declare', [{queue, <<"incoming">>}, durable]},
                        {'exchange.declare',[{exchange, <<"my-exchange-topic">>},{type, <<"topic">>},durable]},
                        {'queue.bind',[{exchange, <<"my-exchange-topic">>},{queue, <<"incoming">>}]}
                ]}]},
                {destinations, [{broker, "amqp://guest:guest@172.16.3.162:5672/blah"},
                    {declarations,
                    [
                        {'queue.declare',[{queue, <<"billing">>},durable]},
                        {'exchange.declare',[{exchange, <<"my-exchange-topic">>},{type, <<"topic">>},{alternate_exchange, <<"alt">>}, durable]},
                        {'queue.bind',[{exchange, <<"my-exchange-topic">>},{queue, <<"billing">>},{routing_key, <<"physical">>}]}
                    ]}
                ]},
                {queue, <<"incoming">>},
                {ack_mode, no_ack},
                {publish_properties, [{delivery_mode, 2}]},
                {reconnect_delay, 5}
                ]}
            ]
        }]
    }
].
```

The problem is on the destination exchange called my-exchange-topic. If I take out the declarations section then the config file works.

This is the error:

=INFO REPORT==== 31-Jul-2012::12:15:25 ===
    application: rabbitmq_shovel
    exited: {{invalid_shovel_configuration,call_stats_shovel,
                 {invalid_parameter_value,destinations,
                     {unknown_fields,'exchange.declare',
                         [alternate_exchange]}}},
             {rabbit_shovel,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: permanent

If I leave the alternate_exchange section out of the declaration I get this error in RabbitMQ web management:

> {{shutdown,
>        {server_initiated_close,406,
>            <<"PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'alternate-exchange'for exchange 'my-exchange-topic' in vhost 'blah':
>   received none but current is the value 'alt' of type 'longstr'">>}}, 
>   {gen_server,call,
>        [<0.473.0>,
>         {call,
>             {'exchange.declare',0,<<"my-exchange-topic">>,<<"topic">>,false,
>                 true,false,false,false,[]},
>             none,<0.444.0>},
>         infinity]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking at how to configure exchanges and queues that require additional arguments you do it like this:

```
{'exchange.declare',[{exchange, <<"my-exchange-topic">>},{type, <<"topic">>}, durable, {arguments, [{<<"alternate-exchange">>, longstr, <<"alternate-exchange">>}]}  ]},
```

you can do a similar thing with queues:

```
{'queue.declare',[{queue, <<"my-queue">>},durable, {arguments, [{<<"x-dead-letter-exchange">>, longstr, <<"dead-letter-queue">>}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarification of the comment above, in case of an exchange2exchange shovel, the config would be:

```
{'exchange.declare',[{exchange, <<"my-exchange-topic">>},{type, <<"topic">>}, durable, {arguments, [{<<"alternate-exchange">>, longstr, <<"name-of-your-alternate-exchange">>}]}  ]},
```